# jquery don't add class to specified array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, addclass

I have the HTML below

```
<span class="post-labels">
    <a href="http://myblog.blogspot.com/search/label/jQuery%20Downloads">jQuery Donwloads</a>
    <a href="http://myblog.blogspot.com/search/label/jQuery">jQuery</a>
    <a href="http://myblog.blogspot.com/search/label/mootools">mootools</a>
    <a href="http://myblog.blogspot.com/search/label/css">css</a>
    <a href="http://myblog.blogspot.com/search/label/blogger">blogger</a>
    <a href="http://myblog.blogspot.com/search/label/wordpress">wordpress</a>
</span>​
```

the jquery below adds class to `<a>` elements ACCEPT for the url `http://myblog.blogspot.com/search/label/jQuery%20Downloads`  http://jsfiddle.net/qbrN8/10/

```
$(".post-labels a").each(function(){
var domain = "http://myblog.blogspot.com/search/label/";
var dontadd = "jQuery Downloads";
var encode = encodeURI(dontadd);    
var url = domain + encode; 
var posta = $(this).attr("href");
if(posta!=url){
$(this).addClass("addedclass");
}
```

});

---

I am trying to create an array to exclude multiple specified urls with the jquery below BUT it doesn't work http://jsfiddle.net/qbrN8/11/ .... I never have worked with arrays so i wouldn't know how to fully execute it. i have search but i keep getting result of stuff like `var myarray[0] var myarray[1]` where i would much rather have an array like `var myarray = [];`

```
$(".post-labels a").each(function(){
    var domain = "http://myblog.blogspot.com/search/label/";
    var dontadd = [];
    dontadd.push("jQuery Downloads", "css", "wordpress");
    var encode = encodeURI(dontadd);    
    var url = domain + encode; 
    var posta = $(this).attr("href");
    if(posta!=dontadd){
    $(this).addClass("addedclass");
    }        
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`!=` does not work if you want to check whether an array contains a string. You can use `indexOf`: http://jsfiddle.net/qbrN8/13/.

```
$(".post-labels a").each(function(){
    var domain = "http://myblog.blogspot.com/search/label/";

    var dontadd = ["jQuery Downloads", "css", "wordpress"].map(function(v) {
        return domain + encodeURI(v);
    });
    // `dontadd` is an array of encoded, full URLs

    var posta = $(this).attr("href");

    // `!~` with `indexOf` can be used for "does not contain"
    if(!~dontadd.indexOf(posta)){
        $(this).addClass("addedclass");
    }        
});
```

Comment: Just a note: ``Array.prototype.map`` (in above code, ``[...].map(function(v) {...});`` is ES5 feature.

Answer (score 1):

First : don't declare your "global" variables in your each... it makes you declare these for every elements. It is REALLY not optimized

`var dontadd = ["jQuery Downloads", "css", "wordpress"],
        domain = "http://myblog.blogspot.com/search/label/";
    $(".post-labels a").each( ...`

Second : You have to check if label is in dontadd, not if label is dontadd => `if (dontadd.indexOf(posta) !== -1)` Working with array means that you have a collection of element, not just one. So you must check if what your looking for " is in ". indexOf returns to you the index (0 to length-1) of the element, -1 if it not exists.

Third : You never worked with array and are using jQuery ? You're doing it the wrong way. 
You must come back to 0, read and learn about **Javascript** bases, learn how to create a librarie etc... When you'll be able to make things like the one you're using, you'll be able to learn how to use jQuery.